# Flutter Row Widget refuses to grow in height to accomodate children widgets, forcing a bottom overflow, how to solve?

Tags: flutter, row, overflow

For smaller screens I need the icons to be able to wrap around, and the banner to grow to accommodate them.  The present Icons are dummy ones, there will most likely be less for most profile pages, but could be more.

At present the icons wrap around inside their parent `Wrap`, they push the lower `TextButton.icon` down, which is then pushed out of it's parent Row.  Disaster!  My first parent Row Widget is unwilling to grow to accommodate changes in height.

I've tried switching Row to a Wrap but it makes the photo go full screen, which spooked me.  I tried changing it to a column, which had a similar effect, also vanishing the nested right hand column parenting icons etc.

I've played with Flutter's layout inspector, but I find that confusing at present.  There's lots of things I don't understand.

1. Why won't the Row grow to accommodate the height of it's child
   Column?
2. Given neither Row, nor it parent Container widget have a
   defined height, how are they setting their height if they're not
   doing it to accommodate children's height?
3. The icons are contained
   in a Wrap widget, is that doing something weird to the calculation
   of parent Widgets height?
4. **What is the most suitable Widget to correctly allow the right hand Column to grow in height while forcing the left hand photo to also
   grow?**

[image]

```
Container(
    color: Color(0xFF462c22),
    child: Row(children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Hero(
          tag: "Loaner${widget.job.employerId ?? widget.job.employerName}",
          child: Image(
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          image: NetworkToFileImage(
              file: fileFromDocsDir("${widget.job.employerId}" + ".jpg"),
              url: widget.job.employerPic,
              debug: true),
        ),),
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Wrap(spacing: 20, runSpacing: 8, children: [
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.swimmingPool,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.skiing,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.swimmer,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.footballBall,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.userNinja,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.guitar,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.campground,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.globeEurope,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.utensils,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tree,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.print,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.car,
                          size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),


        Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.utensils,
            size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
        Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tree,
            size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
        Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.print,
            size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),
        Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.car,
            size: headerIconSize, color: Color(0xFF8a5644)),

                        //Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.ellipsisH, size: 22, color: Color(0xFF8a5644))
                      ],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox.shrink(),
                    ),

                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: headerIconSize),
                        label: Text(
                            "${employerName.toUpperCase()}\'S CONTRIBUTION"),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    )
                  ])))
    ]));
```

Comment: Try using LayoutBuilder

Comment: That's a really interesting Widget, I'll definitely be using that elsewhere.  But for this particular case there are no constraints on the size the parent  Container & it's child's Row's height can be.  I just need to choose parent widgets that happily wrap their children whilst preserving the existing design.

Comment: How about you give a fixed width or height to the topmost `Container` so that the Expanded widget will fill the space?

Comment: Yes good idea, I've placed Spacer() either side of the Wrap Widget, so it doesn't look so unevenly spaced & unfinished on larger screens.  I'd prefer a way to just have the Container forced to Wrap it's children but that'll do.  Thanks Bruno.